# Accessing memory allocated on CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I don't really have any experience with CUDA. I have C++ script that looks like the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  // out_data here is a pointer to some chunk of memory on a CPU
  out_data[i] = manipulate_out_data_val(out_data[i]);
}
```

This is currently set up for CPUs. I would like to adapt this to work with GPU allocated arrays, i.e., if `out_data` was allocated on GPU, how can do I write the above loop?

I tried porting it over as is with a GPU-allocated array, and the program seg-faults.

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but `manipulate_out_data_val` applies a constant scaling factor to the input value and then adds a constant to the resulting scaled value.

Comment: You mean to say you want to convert this into a CUDA kernel? If I'm correct, CUDA arrays can only be processed in a CUDA kernel. An ideal example would be to copy your CPU array into GPU using `cudaMemcpy` and convert your for loop in a CUDA kernel. 
Take a look at this example https://gist.github.com/vo/3899348#file-vecadd-cu-L8

Comment: @votelessbubble I will take a look at the link. I think the answer to your question is "yes" but I really have no experience with CUDA & GPUs. I was thinking this would be an easy change, but it seems I have to look into it in detail

Answer (score 1):

So firstly, I will convert your function into a CUDA kernel which looks something like this.

```
__global__ void manipulate_out_data_val(int *array)
{
   // Assuming `20` is just a scaling factor.
   array[threadIdx.x] *= 20; 
}
```

Please note that for loops will not be used anymore because of the `threadIdx` parameter that is provided by CUDA. The thread's index replaces the `i` from your for loop. Please refer to [this document](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-refresher-cuda-programming-model/) to learn more about the CUDA's threading model.

Lets assume the array can store up to 100 integers.

```
int n = 100;
int bytes = n * sizeof(int);
```

Initialise an array on the CPU first.

```
int *arr_cpu;
arr_cpu = (int *)malloc(bytes);
for(int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
    arr_cpu[i] = i;
}
```

Allocate some memory on the GPU

```
int *arr_gpu;
cudaMalloc((void **)&arr_gpu, n*sizeof(int));
```

Now, you can copy your CPU array to this allocated GPU memory using the `cudaMemcpu` function. Note that `Host` indicates CPU and `Device` indicates GPU as stated [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/easy-introduction-cuda-c-and-c/)

```
cudaMemcpy(arr_gpu, arr_cpu, n * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Finally you can run your kernel. Note the number `1` in kernel syntax is number of blocks and `n` is number of threads per block.

```
manipulate_out_data_val<<<1, n>>>(arr_gpu);
```

Wait until the kernel is finished running

```
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

Finally, you can move the array from GPU back to CPU

```
cudaMemcpy(arr_cpu, arr_gpu, n * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Please find the whole code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>
using namespace std;

__global__ void manipulate_out_data_val(int *array)
{
   // Can add your constant scaling logic here
   array[threadIdx.x] *= 20; 
}


int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
   int n = 100;
   int bytes = n * sizeof(int);
   
   int *arr_cpu;
   arr_cpu = (int *)malloc(bytes);

   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      arr_cpu[i]=i;

   int *arr_gpu;
   cudaMalloc((void **)&arr_gpu, n*sizeof(int));

   printf("Copying to device..\n");
   cudaMemcpy(arr_gpu, arr_cpu, n * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

   manipulate_out_data_val<<<1, n>>>(arr_gpu);
   cudaDeviceSynchronize();

   cudaMemcpy(arr_cpu, arr_gpu, n * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     printf("%d,", arr_cpu[i]);

   cudaFree(arr_gpu);
   return 0;
}
```

Build and run using:

```sh
# program.cu is the file containing the code
nvcc program.cu -o program

# Run
./program
```

The above code has been tested on CUDA 11.4.

Comment: n can be up to 1024, above more than one CUDA block is needed. The `20` can be given as kernel parameter. In C++ there are of course better alternatives to `malloc` (the corresponding `free` is missing anyway, use `std::array` or `std::vector`), but it shows well the same program structure between CPU and GPU. If you copy back `cudaDeviceSynchronize` is not necessary.